# how to escape spaces and breaks in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

When I fetch data from my database to my php. I get and when I check it's source it looks something like this:

```
  <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="chk" name="countryname[]" value="AF 
" > AFGHANISTAN`
```

in the `value` field you can see there is space after `AF`. Now the problem which occurs here is that these space are not in database and i want to skip these spaces and this is not even in my php code. Well they could be in my database but I want to skip them or delete them from database.

Here is my code
`<ul id="sortable"> <? while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?> <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="chk" name="countryname[]" value="<?echo urldecode($row['Code']);?>" <? $reflex = mysql_query("select distinct * from geocity where isAllowed='1' AND country='" . $row['Code'] . "'"); $count = mysql_num_rows($reflex); if ($count == 0){echo '';}else{echo 'checked';} ?>>&nbsp;<? echo $row['CountryName']; ?> </li> <? }; ?>`

Comment: so go look at the code that generates this html. if the spaces/breaks aren't in the db, then php is the obvious next stop for checking.

Comment: we'd need to see your code but maybe you have something like `echo "$country['code'] ";` in your php. with a space, i mean.

Comment: Do you have any php-code?

Comment: @HAB - Please edit your question and put your code there instead :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TRIM(BOTH ' \r\n\t' FROM [the column name])` when you select your data to remove bogus endings and beginnings.

In PHP you can just use `trim()`, as it already also removes tabs, newlines and such.

If you clean up those fields in the database you also should look for breaks inside the strings and kill them with REPLACE :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
trim($value)
```

Also some code would be helpful

Comment: TRIM() only removes spaces and only at the very beginning or ending

Comment: @nicogawenda - wasn't that the point? to remove space at the end?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: and breaks;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to find the content between the  double quotes then remove the spaces from the contents? I would suggest trim as Jim did, but that is for white space at the beginning and end of a string.